# Ignore or overwrite templating in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm new to Drupal. I have a page template that has a nav, header and footer. This works correctly for how I want most of my site, except for the login page that I would like to completely customize.

Is there a way to overwrite or ignore the overall site templating (perhaps by placing my login page template into a folder within the **/templates** directory?) in order to style that one page differently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking out for customizing only the login page without its effect on anywhere in the site, you can use **page--user--login.tpl.php** to override it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you should find system template you want to override. It may be part of standard drupal installation but also part of some module. Copy it to your theme's templates directory and change the way you like. Clear the cache and drupal will re-scan your theme and start using templates you added instead of original one.